# Show 1 div, hide 2 others...Media Query not working

Tags: css

Instead of showing 1 div at a time, I'm seeing all 3 divs at the widest, and they are disappearing as I shrink the page.  I can't figure out why...

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1400px){
#W1400px { display: block;}  
#W1280px { display: none;}  
#W1024px { display: none;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px){
#W1400px { display: none;}   
#W1280px { display: block;}
#W1024px { display: none;}  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1024px){
#W1400px { display: none;}  
#W1280px { display: none;}  
#W1024px { display: block;}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `and (max-width: 1400px)` from your first media query.

Currently this block only applies when the viewport is narrower than 1400px. If the viewport is wider than 1400px all three divs will be displayed.

`(min-width: 0px)` is also unnecessary and can be removed.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  #W1400px {
    display: block;
  }
  #W1280px {
    display: none;
  }
  #W1024px {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px) {
  #W1400px {
    display: none;
  }
  #W1280px {
    display: block;
  }
  #W1024px {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #W1400px {
    display: none;
  }
  #W1280px {
    display: none;
  }
  #W1024px {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="W1400px">
  W1400px
</div>
<div id="W1280px">
  W1280px
</div>
<div id="W1024px">
  W1024px
</div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a conflict when the viewport hits `1024px` or `1280px`..  Does cascading play a role then?

Comment: Order of declaration applies to media queries just like any other CSS. At 1024 the last query will be applied. At the 1280; the second.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, remember, the css is case sensitive

```
@media  (min-width: 1281px){
#w1400px { display: block;}  
#w1280px { display: none;}  
#w1024px { display: none;}
}

@media  (min-width: 1025px){
#w1400px { display: none;}   
#w1280px { display: block;}
#w1024px { display: none;}  
}

@media (max-width: 1024px){
#w1400px { display: none;}  
#w1280px { display: none;}  
#w1024px { display: block;}
}
```